# What role do Engineering Manager, Product Manager & Technical Project Manager play in Software Engineer's day to day work?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, software, software-engineering

I'm new to the industry & self taught. I'd say I'm pretty decent when it comes to writing code and delivering a project however lately I've realized that software engineering is much more than that.

I've recently joined a company as a software engineer where a product involves several actors like PM, EM & TPM and I feel like I'm missing the much needed context about these roles and how do they fit in software engineering & how & in what ways can they support a software engineer.

I've been struggling to wrap my head around the roles of PM, EM & TPM and what does their role entail? As a software engineer myself where do these roles fit in in my day to day work?

I've looked around internet but couldn't really grasp when should a SWE reach out to EM, PM & TPM, what do they offer to a software engineer & how can I leverage these roles to get my job done more efficiently & in decision making?

It's probably a naive question for industry veterans but I've learned that no question is a stupid question. I'd appreciate your help with it.

SWE = Software engineer

EM = Engineering Manager

PM = Product Manager

TPM = Technical Project Manager

Comment: Do you have the "standard" definitions for any of those? Even for software engineer it can vary.

Answer (score 8):

> I've been struggling to wrap my head around the roles of PM, EM & TPM
> and what does their role entail? As a software engineer myself where
> do these roles fit in in my day to day work?
>
> I've looked around internet but couldn't really grasp when should a
> SWE reach out to EM, PM & TPM, what do they offer to a software
> engineer & how can I leverage these roles to get my job done more
> efficiently & in decision making?

You should ask at work.

Different companies define those roles differently, and have different expectations regarding how you should all interact.

Answer (score 0):

Joe is right, it's all company specific in detail.

But in general most of the time these roles reach out to you rather than the other way around. Your job is to implement their decisions, provide assistance and feedback etc,.. There are exceptions, but in the main it works this way.

As far as day to day work is concerned you may not have contact with some of them for days or longer.